# Python global variable changing for some functions but not others in loop

Tags: python, loops, google-analytics, global-variables

I'm sure someone's answered something similar before, but those posts seem to have been lost amongst more popular questions about global variables and loops.

What I'm trying to do is write a loop to step through the Google Analytics API, pulling out data one day at a time. I'm sure there are already some packages that do this but it's somewhat of a learning experience for me.

Where I'm getting stuck is that my loop seems to be progressing the correct number of days however the actual request being sent to the GA Reporting API (V4) isn't updating with the global variable, even though a simple print() seems to indicate it does update.

Here's my code:

```
# Reporting API V4

from apiclient.discovery import build
from oauth2client.service_account import ServiceAccountCredentials

# Import JSON
import json

# Open JSON config file
jsonConfig = open("config.json", "r")

# Parse the JSON file
configRead = json.loads(jsonConfig.read())

# Define global vars

SCOPES = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/analytics.readonly']
KEY_FILE_LOCATION = configRead['keyFileLocation']
VIEW_ID = 12345678 # made up for this exercise

startDate = 732
endDate = 732

# Define report #1
request1 = {
        'reportRequests': 
        [
          {
            'viewId': VIEW_ID,
            'dateRanges': 
            [
              {
                'startDate': f'{startDate}daysAgo',
                'endDate': f'{endDate}daysAgo'
              }
            ],
            'metrics': 
            [
              {
                'expression': 'ga:sessions'
              }
            ],
            'dimensions': 
            [
              {
                'name': 'ga:date'
              }
            ],
            'pageSize': 1
          }
        ]
      }

def initialize_analyticsreporting():
  # Initializes an Analytics Reporting API V4 service object.
  # Returns: An authorized Analytics Reporting API V4 service object.

  credentials = ServiceAccountCredentials.from_json_keyfile_name(
      KEY_FILE_LOCATION, SCOPES)

  # Build the service object
  analytics = build('analyticsreporting', 'v4', credentials=credentials)

  return analytics


def get_report(analytics):
  # Queries the Analytics Reporting API V4.
  # Args: _ analytics _ : An authorized Analytics Reporting API V4 service object.
  # Returns: The Analytics Reporting API V4 response.
  global startDate
  global endDate
  global request1

  return analytics.reports().batchGet(
      body=request1
      ).execute()

def print_response(response):

  # Parses and prints the Analytics Reporting API V4 response.
  # Args: _ response _ : An Analytics Reporting API V4 response.

  for report in response.get('reports', []):
    columnHeader = report.get('columnHeader', {})
    dimensionHeaders = columnHeader.get('dimensions', [])
    metricHeaders = columnHeader.get('metricHeader', {}).get('metricHeaderEntries', [])

    for row in report.get('data', {}).get('rows', []):
      dimensions = row.get('dimensions', [])
      dateRangeValues = row.get('metrics', [])

      for header, dimension in zip(dimensionHeaders, dimensions):
        print(header + ': ', dimension)

      for i, values in enumerate(dateRangeValues):
        for metricHeader, value in zip(metricHeaders, values.get('values')):
          print(metricHeader.get('name') + ':', value)


def main():
  global startDate
  global endDate

  analytics = initialize_analyticsreporting()
  while startDate >= 725:
    response = get_report(analytics)
    print(f'{startDate}daysAgo')
    print_response(response)
    startDate -= 1
    endDate -= 1
  print("Done now, cheers")

if __name__ == '__main__':
  main()
```

In that specific example, it's getting startDate and endDate to update within request1 when it loops.

Output as it currently stands:

```
732daysAgo
ga:date:  20181123
ga:sessions: 2887
731daysAgo
ga:date:  20181123
ga:sessions: 2887
730daysAgo
ga:date:  20181123
ga:sessions: 2887
729daysAgo
ga:date:  20181123
ga:sessions: 2887
728daysAgo
ga:date:  20181123
ga:sessions: 2887
727daysAgo
ga:date:  20181123
ga:sessions: 2887
726daysAgo
ga:date:  20181123
ga:sessions: 2887
725daysAgo
ga:date:  20181123
ga:sessions: 2887
Done now, cheers
```

Any idea what might be the issue?

Comment: You're not expecting `req1`'s value to somehow change when `startDate` and `endDate` do, are you? You only define `req1` once with your class definition. It's not going to dynamically change; if you wanted it to, you'd have to make it be dynamically built and then returned every time some function was called.

Comment: Good pick up - something I was playing with to try and get it to work. I've changed it back to being a standard variable now and updated the original post to reflect that.

Comment: That doesn't change anything; `request1` is only set when you define it, changing `startDate` and `endDate` will still have zero effect on `request1`.

Comment: Oh, didn't know that. How would I have the values within that dynamically change? As you can probably tell, I'm pretty new to Python (other than a little copy and paste work). Would I have to set it as a simple function rather than a static variable?

Comment: Yes, that's what I meant by "you'd have to make it by dynamically build and then returned every time some function was called". I'll post an answer demonstrating how your function could look.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that you want `request1` to be dynamically generated depending on the values of `startDate` and `endDate`, but you currently only define `request1` once at the beginning of your program, so it'll never change its definition depending on either of those variables.

To have `request1` be dynamic, you can create a function that returns the request instead:

```
startDate = 732 
endDate = 732
VIEW_ID = 12345678

def get_request1():
    global startDate
    global endDate
    global VIEW_ID
    
    return {
    'reportRequests': 
    [
      {
        'viewId': VIEW_ID,
        'dateRanges': 
        [
          {
            'startDate': f'{startDate}daysAgo',
            'endDate': f'{endDate}daysAgo'
          }
        ],
        'metrics': 
        [
          {
            'expression': 'ga:sessions'
          }
        ],
        'dimensions': 
        [
          {
            'name': 'ga:date'
          }
        ],
        'pageSize': 1
      }
    ]
  }
```

Thus, every time you call `get_request1()`, its returned value will always contain the current values of start and end date.

Comment: Legendary. Thank you. Worked a treat and you helped me learn a fundamental Python concept which I hadn't had explained to me. Any way I can throw a tip your way?

Comment: @PuGZoR accepting my answer is more than enough. Glad that helped. You can pay it forward by helping someone else in the future, maybe.